# Processes running under taskhost on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c, windows-phone-8

This question is in the context of Windows Phone 8. As far as I understand, TASKHOST is a generic process which acts as a host for processes that run from DLLs rather than EXEs, and there can be many instances of TASKHOST running, as there will be one instance of TASKHOST for every DLL-based service. So, if I need to find out what apps are running under TASKHOST, is there a way to do so? For example, is there any way to get an handle of each instance of TASKHOST and find out more about the process running under each? (Basically, I need to find out if the app I'm trying to launch (not exe) is already running)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

No way to do this with the current API, the apps are all sandboxed.